# How to restore one record/row in table when testing?

Tags: java, database, oracle, restore

I am conducting Junit test on an AM.

The thing is that, in some cases there are changes to the values of the attributes in one row, sometimes even have to delete the whole row in the table.

How can I restore the row in a Java programming way at the end of each test case because I don't want to change the data in DB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) for specific rows which will update or insert record as needed. Example:

> MERGE INTO bonuses D    USING (SELECT employee_id, salary,
>   department_id FROM employees    WHERE department_id = 80) S    ON
>   (D.employee_id = S.employee_id)    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
>   D.bonus = D.bonus + S.salary*.01
>        DELETE WHERE (S.salary > 8000)    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (D.employee_id, D.bonus)
>        VALUES (S.employee_id, S.salary*.01)
>        WHERE (S.salary <= 8000);

In java call it with PreparedStatement, for example:

```
preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement("Merge ..");
```

Another option which isn't for use in production is [flashback](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9012.htm#SQLRF01802) which can add restore point which you can return to.

Comment: Thanks...But the thing is that, if we have deleted the whole row, how can we insert it in the table? There is no primary key or other information anymore.

Comment: If you delete a row with Primary key as Id 1. You delete the primary key also

Comment: Yes, that's true. The point is how to restore one deleted row in the table rather than just insert one row... How can it come true?

Comment: Add 1 more solution